# Keyboard Caret Navigation in MultiLine WPF TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListView using a multi-line TextBox as its DataTemplate.

By default, in a multi-line TextBox, up and down arrow navigation is enabled. If your TextBox has two lines, the caret is on the first line and you press the down arrow, it puts the caret on the second line at the same relative position.

I've additionally added cursor navigation between TextBoxes in the ListView. If you're at the first line of a TextBox and press the up arrow, it sets the focus to the previous TextBox in the ListView. Similarly, if you're at the last line and press down, it goes to the next TextBox. But because this has to be done manually, I've had to write my own logic for maintaining the relative position. But it's complicated and has some problems.

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = (sender as TextBox);
    var textBeforeCursor = tb.Text.Substring(0, tb.SelectionStart);
    var textAfterCursor = tb.Text.Substring(tb.SelectionStart);

    if (e.Key == Key.Up && !textBeforeCursor.Contains("\r\n"))
    {
        var caretIndex = GetTextBoxCaretIndex();
        listView.SelectedIndex--;

        var lastLineRegex = new Regex("(.*)(\r\n.*$)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        var previousString = listView.SelectedItem as string;
        var lines = lastLineRegex.Match(previousString);
        var offset = lines.Groups[1].Length;

        FocusTextBox(caretIndex + offset + 2);
    }
    if (e.Key == Key.Down && !textAfterCursor.Contains("\r\n"))
    {
        var caretIndex = GetTextBoxCaretIndex();
        var lastLineRegex = new Regex("(.*)(\r\n.*$)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        var previousString = listView.SelectedItem as string;
        var lines = lastLineRegex.Match(previousString);
        var offset = lines.Groups[1].Length;
        listView.SelectedIndex++;

        Console.WriteLine($"CaretIndex: {caretIndex}, Offset: {offset}");
        FocusTextBox(caretIndex - offset - 2);
    }
}

private int GetTextBoxCaretIndex()
{
    var item = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listView.SelectedItem) as ListViewItem;
    var textBox = GetVisualChildOfType<TextBox>(item);
    return textBox.CaretIndex;
}
private void FocusTextBox(int caretIndex = 0)
{
    var item = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listView.SelectedItem) as ListViewItem;
    var textBox = GetVisualChildOfType<TextBox>(item);

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
    {
        textBox.CaretIndex = Math.Min(caretIndex, textBox.Text.Length);
        textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.CaretIndex;
        textBox.Focus();
    }));
}
```

This logic kind of works, but in some cases breaks the default caret navigation between lines.

[Here's a .gif of one example case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3M2T.gif)

The caret is on the bottom line of the top text box, 8 characters over. I press down, it goes to the second TextBox, with the caret on the first line, 8 characters over; Expected behavior.

I then press down again, and it goes to the second line, but at the first character rather than the 8th. My code is not executing in this situation, so something unusual is happening with the default logic.

I'm not even sure where to start with this. Through testing it *seems* like the TextBox has some internal state about the caret position on each line, but through looking at TextBox docs I don't see any properties regarding this.

You can view a pared-down example project and full code demonstrating the issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/Magdain/TextboxCursorNavigationTest).

Any help or information about how the default caret navigation works would be helpful. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see your frustration. As I tried this I found some weird behavior with the Caret. It seems when you edit the Caret position the default behavior is removed (why it went to the beginning of the line). So i went under the assumption that you then have to always control the caret position. thus i added `else` clauses to your `Key_Up` and `Key_Down` checks. I repeated your logic, but made it so the caret position is explicitly controlled within the textbox.

```
     //...if (e.Key == Key.Up && !textBeforeCursor.Contains("\r\n")){...}
     else if (e.Key == Key.Up)
     {
        var caretIndex = GetTextBoxCaretIndex();

        var lastLineRegex = new Regex("(.*)(\r\n.*$)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        var previousString = listView.SelectedItem as string;
        var lines = lastLineRegex.Match(previousString);
        var offset = lines.Groups[1].Length;

        FocusTextBox(caretIndex - offset - 2);
     }
    //...if (e.Key == Key.Down && !textAfterCursor.Contains("\r\n")){...}
    else if(e.Key ==  Key.Down)
    {
        var caretIndex = GetTextBoxCaretIndex();
        var lastLineRegex = new Regex("(.*)(\r\n.*$)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        var previousString = listView.SelectedItem as string;
        var lines = lastLineRegex.Match(previousString);
        var offset = lines.Groups[1].Length;
        FocusTextBox(caretIndex + offset + 2);
    }
```

The code can definitely be cleaned up. I left it as is, because it allowed for debugging at each stage. Thus, i will leave it up to you for refactoring as you see fit. You would also have to add `null` checks on `previousString`.

Comment: The code as provided doesn't meet my needs because it never changes the ListView's selected index. I had not thought, however, of manually handling all arrow key logic. That seems like a plausible solution. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The ListView Selected Index is changed in your current code. under your if statements (as i commented in my code). Your question only stated that you were trying to solve the issue that you see in the GIF. This code is intended to be inserted into yours

Answer (score 1):

The solution ultimately was to manually control the cursor in all cases, but separate logic was required. The idea being, get the caret position relative to the beginning of the current line, and set it's new position to the next line's first character plus the relative position, accounting for if the next line is smaller than the current line.

```
if (e.Key == Key.Up)
{
    if (!textBeforeCursor.Contains("\r\n"))
    {
        var caretIndex = GetTextBoxCaretIndex();
        listView.SelectedIndex--;

        var lastLineRegex = new Regex("(.*)(\r\n.*$)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        var previousString = listView.SelectedItem as string;
        var lines = lastLineRegex.Match(previousString);
        var offset = lines.Groups[1].Length;

        FocusTextBox(caretIndex + offset + 2);
    }
    else
    {
        var item = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listView.SelectedItem) as ListViewItem;
        var textBox = GetVisualChildOfType<TextBox>(item);
        var currentLineIndex = textBox.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(textBox.CaretIndex);
        var positionOnCurrentLine = textBox.CaretIndex - textBox.GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex(currentLineIndex);

        var nextLineIndex = currentLineIndex - 1;
        var lineStartIndex = textBox.GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex(nextLineIndex);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {
            var modifier = textBox.GetLineText(nextLineIndex).Contains("\r\n") ? 2 : 0;
            textBox.CaretIndex = Math.Min(
                lineStartIndex + positionOnCurrentLine,
                lineStartIndex + textBox.GetLineLength(nextLineIndex) - modifier);
        }));
    }
}
```

The logic is identical for the down arrow key, but you change nextLineIndex to be currentLineIndex + 1.

This solution is inferior to the default caret management, because the default management accounts for if you're on the end of a line (regardless of length), and keeps you on the line end until you manually change it. This solution also sometimes picks a slightly unexpected position because characters have different widths.

I tried a solution that used TextBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex and TextBox.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint, but it didn't seem like an improvement in functionality. Perhaps there is a better way.